# How to get the path to the executable in the current file?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I`m running test in suite in protractor.

```
protractor config/protractor.conf.js --suite currentSuite
```

I want to know the path to the current running file (spec) in the suite.
(etc. if my current describe in file folder/.../name.spec.js I want see the path to my current spec in `console.log()` in my plugin reporter).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: you are making a jasmine reporter for Protractor and want to get the suite name from the reporter? Thanks.

Comment: I want to get path to curent spec in reporter

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation tells you, Protractor runs on NodeJS. The NodeJS documentation tells us we can access the NodeJS command arguments via [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

Comment: ```javascript
process.argv.forEach( function (val, index) {
      console.log(index + ':' + val);
    });
```

  
return  
0:C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe  
1:c:\Git\web_inq_proc\test\e2e\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js  
2:config/protractor.conf.js  
3:--suite  
4:extendedFilterClient,extendedFilterTreatment

Answer (score 0):

```
    console.log(process.cwd() + __filename);
```

This will fetch you the current running spec/file